# Datatables - Rendering multiple columns together with headings for data

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am combining multiple columns into one using the Datables [render](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) method:

```
var table = $( '#unit_outcomes_table' ).DataTable( {
                responsive: true,
                ajax: "program_data/unit_outcome_data.php",
                dom: "Blfrtip",
                columns: [ {
                    data: "unit_outcome.unit_outcome",
                    width: '50%'
                }, {
                    data: null,
                    render(data, type, row) {
                    return []
                    .concat(row.emergency_medicine, row.general_practice, row.internal_medicine, row.obstetrics_gynaecology, row.paediatrics, row.psychiatry, row.surgery, row.infection_immunity)
                    .map(r => r.discipline_outcome)
                    .join(', ');
                    }
                }],
                select: {
                    style: 'os',
                    selector: 'td:first-child'
                },
                buttons: []
            } );
```

For each of the column datasets, e.g. `row.emergency_medicine, row.general_practice` etc. I want to have headings so the data looks like:

**Emergency Medicine**

ed outcome 1

ed outcome 2

**General Practice**

gp outcome 1

gp outcome 2

etc

I guess this can be done by looping through the results by adding the title for the emergency medicine first, then loop over that array adding the values. Then concat the title for general practice, loop over the values adding them, etc.  But I am unsure specifically how to do this.

Comment: This should get you really close to your answer. https://jsfiddle.net/codeandcloud/rqebz583/